# Insertion sort with a string vector

Tags: c++, vector, insertion-sort

I am trying to sort a string vector using insertion sort.

This is my code:

```
void insertionsort(std::vector<std::string> &strings) 
{
    typedef std::vector<std::string>::size_type size_type;
    for(size_type i = 0;i < strings.size(); i++) 
    {
        std::string const tmp = strings[i];
        size_type j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && tmp < strings[j]) //this is the problem
        {
            strings[j + 1]= strings[j];
            j--;

        }
        strings[j + 1]=tmp;
    }
}
```

It gives me the error:

> comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true

The function works fine if I use j > 0. But it completely ignores the first line of the string.

If for example i have:

```
2 line1
3 line2
4 line3
5 line4
1 line5
```

Then it gives me:

```
2 line1
1 line5
3 line2
4 line3
5 line4
```

Comment: Use a signed type. (Not undisputed, but several prominent members of the standards committee are with me on that one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector<T>::size_type` is [by definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) unsigned so `j >= 0` can't be false.  You should use `vector<T>::difference_type`.

Answer (score 1):

The type alias `size_type` of the class template `std::vector` is always non-negative integer type. So the epression

```
j >= 0
```

is always true.

What you need is to make some minor changes in the function implementation. It is evident that a vector that contains only one element is always sorted. So you should start the outer loop with the index equal to 1.

Here you are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void insertionSort( std::vector<std::string> &strings ) 
{
    typedef std::vector<std::string>::size_type size_type;

    for ( size_type i = 1; i < strings.size(); ++i ) 
    {
        std::string tmp = strings[i];

        size_type j = i;

        for ( ; j !=  0 && tmp < strings[j-1]; --j )
        {
            strings[j] = strings[j-1];
        }

        if ( j != i ) strings[j] = tmp;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "E", "D", "C", "B", "A" };

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    insertionSort( v );

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
E D C B A 
A B C D E
```

Pay attention to this added statement

```
if ( j != i ) strings[j] = tmp;
```

if an element is already occupies required position in the vector then there is no sense to assign it to itself. This makes the function more efficient.

And it is a bad idea to mix the type `difference_type` with the type `size_type` that is the return type of the member function `size()`.